# Writing a linear transformations $g:V\to F$ from a vector space into a field as an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't understand the answers of solution.

Questions is

For each of the following inner produce spaces $V$ (over $F$) and linear transformations $g:V\to F$, find a vector $y$ such that $g(x) = \langle x,y\rangle$ for 
all $x$ in $V$.

(b) $V = C^2$, $g(z_1, z_2) = z_1 - 2\cdot z_2$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question?  Do you know how to represent this linear transformation by a matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try some different inner products to get you going.

If $x=(z_1,z_2)\in\mathbb{C}^2$, and say $y = (2,1)$, then the function $g_1\colon\mathbb{C}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ defined by $g_1(x) = \langle x,y\rangle$ is more explicitly given as
$$g_1(z_1,z_2) = 2z_1+z_2.$$

So if I had to find a vector $y$, such that $g$ was on the same form as $g_1$, I simply had to take $y=(2,1)$. Note how this $y$ enters into the expression for $g_1$.

If I had instead another function $g_2$ given by
$$g_2(z_1,z_2) = -5z_2,$$
I would choose $y=(0,-5)$. This is because I can write the expression for $g_2$ as $0z_1-5z_2$.

Maybe you can now see what you need to do in your case.